# How to get 1 row from Table A and multiple rows from Table B

Tags: mysql

Table A is named "users" and Table B is named "comments".  I want to select fields "user_id" and "user_name" from Table A and "date", "comment", "user_id" fields in Table B.

In a nutshell I am trying to get all the users and their comments with 1 query. Can the comments be put in its own array as there will be multiple comments like below or will it just be 1 comment and would have to run 2 queries?

Basic Example

```
user_id = 1
username = foo
comments[0]['date'] = 1234567890
comments[0]['comment'] = "Hello World!"
comments[1]['date'] = 1234567890
comments[1]['comment'] = "MySQL n00b"
```

Any basic examples would be great so I can get my head round it.

Comment: What is given at the time you run the query? Do you have `user_id` given, or any other detail? What is the server side language, PHP? How are you doing it at the moment, what else have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a general query, to select all the comments of `user_id` = 1.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, c.`date`, c.`comment`
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE c.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear but how would I bring up all users and comments, would I just remove the WHERE clause? Thanks

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user_id is `1`, here is the code if you want an associative array with all user's comments. There is only one query, using JOIN statement.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT users.user_id as uid, users.user_name as username, comments.date, comments.comment, comments.user_id as cid FROM `users` LEFT JOIN comments on uid=cid WHERE cid = 1");

$i = 0;
while($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
     $comments[$i]['date'] = $arr['date'];
     $comments[$i]['comment'] = $arr['comment'];
     $i++;
}

//var_dump($comments);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it be possible to just have 1 row per user and all comments or would I have to go through the results myself to have just 1 user and comments.

Answer (score 0):

We call this JOIN. Better to take some sql/mysql tutorial or you get lost.